# How can I have a program that core dumps and doesn't from gdb?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, coredump

I have an assembly program that core dumps when started alone, but doesn't when started from gdb. Why ? And why does it core dumps ? How to find out ?

The c++ version is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool a = true;
    bool b = false;
    bool r = a && b;
    cout << (r ? "true" : "false") << endl;
}
```

The assembly source (AT&T):

```
.text
.globl main
main:
movb $0x1,-0x3(%rbp)
movb $0x0,-0x2(%rbp)
cmpb $0x0,-0x3(%rbp)
je falsesomewhere
cmpb $0x0,-0x2(%rbp)
je falsesomewhere
mov $0x1,%rax
falsesomewhere:
mov $0x0,%rax
jmp boolfinal
trueeverywhere:
mov $0x1,%rax
jmp boolfinal
boolfinal:
call print_bool
mov $0, %rax
ret

print_bool:
mov %rdi, %rsi
cmp $0, %rdi
jne swtrue
mov $false, %rdi
jmp end
swtrue:
mov $true, %rdi
end:
mov $0, %rax
call printf
ret

.data
message:.string "%d\n"
true:.string "true\n"
false:.string "false\n"
```

the Makefile:

```
SRC=asprgm
build: $(SRC).s
    as -g $(SRC).s -o $(SRC).o
    gcc $(SRC).o -o $(SRC)
run: build
    ./$(SRC)
debug: build
    gdb ./$(SRC)
```

Hence `make run` core dumps, but `make debug` doesn't.

Comment: Where do you set RBP?

Comment: Your C++ code, compiled with GCC 5.3.1 on Fedora 23 x86_64 does not crash neither running in the shell nor in gdb. Your assembly code crashes both ways because you did not set rbp (push rbp, mov rsp, rbp would be the usual instructions).

Comment: Hint: the very purpose of core dumps is for you to load them into gdb after the fact. So do that and you will see what caused it.

Comment: As for why things run differently. If you don't properly initialize registers they may have different kinds of values depending what environment loads them. This can lead to things working in the debugger and not elsewhere. This lead me to eyeballing your code to find a place where a register was being used without being initialized.

Comment: Argh, Indeed with `push %rbp; mov %rsp,%rbp;` it works ! I'm stacking `%rbp`, but then why `mov %rsp,%rbp` ? I would have done `xor %rbp,%rbp` but this core dumps too ! If I'm working only with registers, why should I use the stack (`push`) ?

Comment: `movb $0x1,-0x3(%rbp)`. Uses RBP as an address to move a byte to. If you use XOR to zero RBP out you would get access of memory -3+0=-3. That is in memory that you can't write to so it would fail with a SIGSEGV. By moving RSP to RBP you are setting RBP to point at the current top of stack which you can use to write bytes to. Note: You can get away with writing 128 bytes of data below RSP without allocating space because of the [64-bit Linux red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) and luckily the way you used the stack